# Which group is simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory, simple-groups

I am currently looking whether a group G of the following order is simple or not

- $ord(G)=100$
- $ord(G')=200$

We have first that for $G$, $ord(G)=2^25^2$. For $G'$ we have that $ord(G')=2^35^2$. Now with the third theorem of Sylow we have, that in both case there is only one $5-$Sylowgroup. But why $G$ is not simple, while $G'$ is simple?
I just try to follow the thinking of this site [Click here](https://yutsumura.com/groups-of-order-100-200-is-it-simple/#a_When_G100)

Comment: "while $G'$ is simple? " Why do you think so? This is not true.

Comment: I suppose you have read the solution [here](https://yutsumura.com/groups-of-order-100-200-is-it-simple/). There is a typo. It should say "Hence $G$
 is **not** a simple group (because it says "Thus the group $G$
 has a unique proper normal $5$-Sylow subgroup of order $25$.")

Comment: Yeah sorry maybe I am just tired but the group of 200 is on this site simple and the group of 100 not. Why? They have both one $5-$ Sylowgroup...

Comment: @DietrichBurde ahhh now everything is clear... I got confused exactly because of this!

Comment: Yes, exactly....you need to read also the argument before.